# SQLServer - convert two queries in a unique query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that store many values that are 'different' by a column (TYPE) value that could be "A", "B" or "C".

When i perform a select to retrieve values, i need to perform some operations like apply a subquery to retrieve an alias value if TYPE equals "A" that is different from subquery to TYPE "B".

Now i have 2 queries: one for type "A" and another for type "B". I would like to put this queries together but i'm not finding a way how to do it.

Type "A"

```
SELECT distinct(l.ProcessId), 
(SELECT Date from Log lt WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId and lt.Message like '%SENDING%') as DateStart,
(SELECT Date from Log lt WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId and lt.Message like '%DONE%') as DateEnd,
DATEDIFF(ss, (SELECT Date from Log lt WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId and lt.Message like '%SENDING%'), (SELECT Date from Log lt WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId and lt.Message like '%DONE%')) as Duration
FROM notifier.Log l where l.Who = 'QueryString' and l.Type = 'A'
```

Type "B"

```
SELECT distinct(l.ProcessId), 
Date as DateStart,
Date as DateEnd,
DATEDIFF(ss, Date, Date) as Duration    
FROM notifier.Log l where l.Type = 'B';
```

How can i perform an unique select to retrieve type "A" and "B"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UNION` for this.

Try this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (l.ProcessId),
    (
        SELECT DATE
        FROM Log lt
        WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId
            AND lt.Message LIKE '%SENDING%'
        ) AS DateStart,
    (
        SELECT DATE
        FROM Log lt
        WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId
            AND lt.Message LIKE '%DONE%'
        ) AS DateEnd,
    DATEDIFF(ss, (
            SELECT DATE
            FROM Log lt
            WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId
                AND lt.Message LIKE '%SENDING%'), (
            SELECT DATE
            FROM Log lt
            WHERE lt.ProcessId = l.ProcessId
                AND lt.Message LIKE '%DONE%'
            )) AS Duration
FROM notifier.Log l
WHERE l.Who = 'QueryString'
    AND l.Type = 'A'

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT (l.ProcessId),
    DATE AS DateStart,
    DATE AS DateEnd,
    DATEDIFF(ss, DATE, DATE) AS Duration
FROM notifier.Log l
WHERE l.Type = 'B'
```

In order to "merge" the result sets of two or more queries into one result set you must use `UNION ALL`.

But be careful that you must have the same number of columns returned by both queries in order for it to work, otherwise you will get an error saying there's not the same number of columns returned by your queries.

Also, you will then be able to further filter this result set by encapsulating your two queries in another `SELECT` statement, but that's already out of the subject.

Comment: It works. If i need to perform a select for type "C", i just put another UNION ALL <my query>?

Comment: @DavidL. Yes, just add another `UNION ALL` and your query after that.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you looking for the UNION {ALL}? which is used to retrieve in one result two separated selects.

e.g.

```
select column_A from table_A where Column_A='Value_A'
UNION ALL
select column_B from table_B where Column_B='Value_B'
```

Keep in mind that the columns must be the same in order for it to work, **union** will join without duplicating rows, meanwhile the **union all** allows duplicated rows.

Regards.